# Difference between UseRouter and UseEndpoints

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to handle requests for a particular path in ASP.NET Core without using controllers.

It seems that I have two options now:

Using the **app.UseRouter(r => r.MapPost(...))**:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseRouter(r => {
        r.MapPost("foo/{fooId:int}/bar", (request, response, routeData) =>
        {
            // My logic
            response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });
    });
}
```

Using the **app.UseEndpoints(e => e.MapPost(...))**:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapPost("foo/{fooId:int}/bar", context =>
        {
            // My logic
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });
    });
}
```

Both options seem to behave identically.

What is the principal difference between the two and which one should I use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between app.UseRouting() and app.UseEndPoints()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57846127/what-are-the-differences-between-app-userouting-and-app-useendpoints)

Comment: No, that question is about UseRouting, not UseRouter.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand:

- **UseRouter** is the old way of routing (defined in .net core 2.1)
- **UseEndpoints** is the new way of routing (defined in .net core 3.0)

**UseEndpoints** supports metadata, context.GetEndpoint() and other powerful features. So it is the preferred option.

UPDATE: Starting from .net 6 both of these approaches are no longer recommended and are replaced with [Minimal API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: I think like to the old one require change to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: @MehdiMowlavi, You have provided a reference to the **mvc controllers** endpoints. It's a little different. There is a special note in the original question: *without using controllers*.

Comment: I could not find other documentation regard UseRouter except this one. Yes the question asking for general routing!