# No overload for method 'UseRouting' takes 1 arguments in Razorpages

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, razor-pages

im trying to show data from my database. I used this website to write my code https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-connect-mysql-with-asp-net-core/ . Everything is going good but in Startup.cs I get this error `error CS1501: No overload for method 'UseRouting' takes 1 arguments`
I don't know what to do. Here is the code:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(pictureContext), new pictureContext(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting(routes => 
                            {
                                routes.MapRoute(
                                    name: "default",
                                    template: "{controller=picture}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                                );
                            });

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
```

Comment: Have a look on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56156657/no-overload-for-method-userouting-takes-1-arguments

Answer (score 0):

The article you are following is for MVC, not Razor Pages. It looks like it was written before Razor Pages was released. The `UseRouting` method doesn't take a single argument (hence the error message), and you don't need to configure routes for controllers in a Razor Pages app, so just call

```
app.UseRouting();
```